# batch file, delete line by number

Tags: batch, windows-command-prompt

i have this: `set myvar = ^J | FIND /N /I "texttolookfor" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`
now i have the lines it fined the text in

how can i delete these line from the file?

i know i can run over the lines with `FOR` but the delete part is still tricky for me

i read about `findstr`, it suppose to be better but can't find anything to delete with that as well

now i read about

```
FIND /V "texttolookfor" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts > newfile
```

it saves the file to a new one without the found string... but adds

> "------------------%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts"

at the begining  but when i try

```
FIND /V "texttolookfor" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts > %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

it does not work...

Comment: `msdos6.22`, but also `%WINDIR%\System32`? I'm confused? Are you editing a windows file on an MS Dos 6.22 system, or is the `msdos6.22` tag a mistake?

Comment: it's within windows... i will fix the tag now

Comment: I feel like you're going about this the wrong way, but it's sort of confusing to figure out what you're actually trying to do. Instead of asking for help on this one specific piece of your problem, why don't you explain your *whole* problem. I'm betting that there's probably a much easier solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command:

```
FIND /V "texttolookfor" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts > newfile
```

adds `------------------%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` to the top of the file as that's part of the default output of `FIND`.  Try it without the redirection and see.

```
FIND /V "texttolookfor" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

---------- C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DRIVERS\ETC\HOSTS
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
...
```

`TYPE` can be used to cat the file, redirect its output *through* `FIND`, and it should not display the file/path:

```
TYPE %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts | FIND /V "texttolookfor"
```

This can, of course, be redirected to a new file as well:

```
TYPE %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts | FIND /V "texttolookfor" > newfile
```

Comment: Oblig. `findstr` example should be `findstr /v /i /c:"texttolookfor" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts > %TEMP%\hosts.tmp && copy /y %TEMP%\hosts.tmp %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`.  Expect admin perms to be a headache on WinV/7/2008/R2, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Win32 port of Grep](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm)

Assuming you want to purge any lines containing `xyz` the following command will do what you need.

```
grep -v xyz inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt
```

If you want to match an entire line, this is possible too using a regular expression. As MDMarra has already said in the comments, please explain the bigger picture of what you are trying to do.

p.s. Piping the output back over the original file, probably isn't a good thing to do, especially when experimenting, and even more especially when it's a system file.

Comment: i know overwriting is not good... but in this case it's a must. any way i can make a backup at c:\ but the export file gets first line of the path and i don't get why